# jupyter lab cannot recognize pandas in my venv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-lab, python-venv

I've created a venv and `pandas==1.4.3` is installed on it. when i run the ipynb code from VScode, it works correctly! but when it's running by jupyterlab, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'` is shown.

I've checked the activation of venv and also the python version and pandas is running correctly from terminal. also another packages run correctly but about pandas, it's not working.
it would be helpful if you have any suggestion.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.